# Bizarre behavior for mp3 mimeMap in IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, mime-types

I have encountered a completely unexpected behavior when adding a mimeMap element for files with mp3 extensions.  This works fine:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
    <!--      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" /> -->
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

But as soon as I uncomment the element pertaining to MP3 files, everything goes to hell in a proverbial handbasket.  Neither my js nor my css nor my aspx files will be served, and I get lots of these:

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Anyone seen this behavior before, or have any pointers?  I am (clearly) less than adept in IIS configuration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

this behavior might be because.. In IIS the mimetype  for mp3 is already configured. 
you adding in web.config mimemap for mp3 will cause duplicate entry.
just do

`<remove fileExtension=".mp3"/>`

`<mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" />`

regards

Goutham Ganesh V

Comment: Hi Goutham -- you're right, that's exactly what it was.  I didn't know you could use a remove entry like that -- very useful.  Thanks!

Comment: This just saved me a lot of time - can I get some more upvotes for this answer?

Comment: This resolves any file type that you want to add in your project. Works like a charm